# Ionic v4 unit test Error: Arguments array must have arguments

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, ionic4

I am facing this error while running unit test cases with jasmin in ionic 4 using -`npm test`.

I also removed node_modules folder then again installed it, but issue still persist. I also made some changes in provider section but nothing worked. While `ionic serve` works without any error.

As per my R&D till now, it seems like in angular 8 `TestBed.get(<ServiceName>)` method is not working.

```
 Error: Arguments array must have arguments.
   Error: Arguments array must have arguments.
    at injectArgs (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:685:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11182:72
    at _callFactory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20295:1)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20253:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20228:1)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20286:1)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20250:1)
    at initNgModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20183:1)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20892:1)
    at createNgModuleRef (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20881:1)
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: What is the Jasmine test?

Comment: Jasmine is an open source testing framework for JavaScript. We use it for unit test as Karma-jasmin in Ionic v4.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I was asking for the test which gives the error ...

Comment: I am doing component level test and performing title check. it was working before update to angular 8.

Comment: It could be either you declared an `empty array` and used it or declared a array and  used it as another `type`.  Can you post your `NgModule` so that it can be easy to debug.

Comment: app.module.ts file ? but it was working before angular update.